# Create a version column based on hash column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I want to add to myDF a version column where put the version of my Hash column. My DF:

```
   Hash    Code   P1  P2  P3  P4  P5... Pn
x-x-1-x-x    A    x   x   1   x   x
x-1-x-x-x    A    x   1   x   x   x
5-x-1-x-x    A    5   x   1   x   x
x-x-1-x-2    A    x   x   1   x   2
x-x-1-x-x    A    x   x   1   x   x
x-x-x-7-x    A    x   x   x   7   x
5-x-1-x-x    A    5   x   1   x   x
```

And i need:

```
Version    Hash    Code   P1  P2  P3  P4  P5... Pn
  1     x-x-1-x-x    A    x   x   1   x   x
  2     x-1-x-x-x    A    x   1   x   x   x
  3     5-x-1-x-x    A    5   x   1   x   x
  4     x-x-1-x-2    A    x   x   1   x   2
  1     x-x-1-x-x    A    x   x   1   x   x
  6     x-x-x-7-x    A    x   x   x   7   x
  3     5-x-1-x-x    A    5   x   1   x   x
```

I'm working with PySpark, don't know if it exists a method that could help me.

**Edit**:
The version column that i need it should be made considering the Hash column. The process should be:

Read the Hash value, exists on previous rows? then put the version value that were assigned previously.
Version value its like an ID, hash could be repeated, if it is, i need to know that version and put in on that row i'm reading. Unless i need to create a new version (id) last value version +1.

Comment: Include an explanation about how the version column is computed so that community can help you.

Comment: @snithish you are right, i didn't explain great. I hope now it is understandable :)

Comment: If the dataset was shuffled would and row with hash `x-x-1-x-x` appears the first time in the 4th row would it still have version 1? If yes, then what is the numbering based on?

Comment: Hash column its created concatenating the rest of the columns (P1, P2, P3, ... Pn).
They are parameters columns, i created the hash column, and i want to have versions and recognize if there are a hash, a parameters configuration that appeared before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  [
     ('x-x-1-x-x','A', 'x', 'x', '1', 'x', 'x'),
     ('x-1-x-x-x','A', 'x', '1', '1', 'x', 'x'),
     ('5-x-x-x-x','A', '5', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'),
     ('x-x-1-x-2','A', 'x', 'x', '1', 'x', '2'),
     ('x-x-1-x-x','A', 'x', 'x', '1', 'x', 'x'),
     ('x-x-x-7-x','A', 'x', 'x', 'x', '7', 'x'),
     ('5-x-x-x-x','A', '5', 'x', '1', 'x', 'x')
  ]
  ,['Hash', 'Code', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5']
)




from pyspark.sql import functions as F

Hash_ids = df\
            .select("Hash")\
            .dropDuplicates()\
            .rdd.zipWithIndex()\
            .toDF()\
            .withColumn("Version", F.col('_2')+1)\
            .select(F.col("_1.*"), F.col("Version"))

df\
  .join(Hash_ids, 'Hash', 'inner')\
  .show()
```